excel vba : Write Timestamp in three specific cells
i need to enter timestamp for specific three cells P1, Q3, V3. I am trying below excel vba code but not
working.
I hope you solve this
Thanks to advance
Sub Start_Click()
With ActiveSheet.Range("p1")
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM"
    .Value = Now()
    .ColumnWidth = 16#
End With
End Sub



Change the p1 to P1, Q3, V3?

As BigBen said it would look exactly as it is, but as ActiveSheet.Range("p1,q3,v3") in the beginning. I needed 21.43 .columnwidth to be able to see all the cell's contents though

Time Stamp to Multiple Cells with NumberFormat and AutoFit
Sub Start_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("P1,Q3,V3")
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Value = Now()
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

